# Troubles with wifi card on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have Ubuntu 12.04.1 and follow wifi equipment:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

And I have this drivers loaded:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
usbhid                 41906  0 
hid                    77367  1 usbhid
parport_pc             32114  0 
rfcomm                 38139  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
bnep                   17830  2 
bluetooth             158438  10 rfcomm,bnep
joydev                 17393  0 
arc4                   12473  2 
snd_hda_codec_si3054    12864  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   174313  1 
pcmcia                 39791  0 
uvcvideo               67203  0 
psmouse                86421  0 
snd_hda_intel          32765  3 
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80845  3 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
ath5k                 145127  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
tifm_7xx1              12937  0 
ath                    19387  1 ath5k
mac80211              436455  1 ath5k
tifm_core              15040  1 tifm_7xx1
serio_raw              13027  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
yenta_socket           27465  0 
pcmcia_rsrc            18367  1 yenta_socket
pcmcia_core            21511  3 pcmcia,yenta_socket,pcmcia_rsrc
snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    62064  16 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
i915                  419070  3 
mac_hid                13077  0 
drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915
cfg80211              178679  3 ath5k,ath,mac80211
drm                   197692  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
soundcore              14635  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
video                  19068  1 i915
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
firewire_ohci          40172  0 
sdhci_pci              18324  0 
sdhci                  28241  1 sdhci_pci
firewire_core          56906  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12627  1 firewire_core
sky2                   53628  0
```

I use NetworkManager for connect to networks, and I just don't succeed... It try, and request password, but don't connect. Befor I installed madwifi driver, and I think that may be it overwrite some libraries.
How can I reinstall original driver or where I can find better driver for my card?

Comment: Can you post the output of `tail /var/log/syslog` ?

Comment: Hi, I tried now and from unknown reason it works... After so much days it didn't worked... Just woodoo... I don't know what I should do - remove question, wait for problems again, put output any way...